# fluentd, config agent-td send request to webservice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fluentd, fluentdata

I 'm new for fluentd. I wonder is it support send a request in fluentd-agentd.

Example: when fluent have new log (from apache/nginx/rails). I want call a request http with body is log text to specify url (http://my_service.com/api/get_log)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. I just did a simple test using the following output plugin:

https://github.com/ento/fluent-plugin-out-http

You can install it with '$ gem install fluent-plugin-out-http' and proceed with the configuration schema proposed on the github repository.

Happy Logging!

Comment: I want send request by Rsyslog, not by rails :)

Comment: Thanks @edsiper, but I don't want to use gem, or any involve to any projects in server.
Config fluent can do that for me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using td-agent then use td-agent-gem to install it. So to install that plugin type: td-agent-gem install fluent-plugin-out-http